# How to IBM MQ - Backup and Clearing Messages on queues in linux?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have tried saveqmgr and dmpmqcfg. i cannot get expected output.

```
dmpmqcfg -m qm.apple -t all -a -x all -o setmqaut
```

I am using MQ_7.5 version. Which command is used to take backup of MQ Message queue in linux

Comment: Do you want to backup the details of the MQ QUEUE object so that it can be recreated or are you looking to backup the messages that are present on the queue?

Comment: backup the details of the MQ QUEUE and backup the messages also @JoshMc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a command similar to the following to backup the details of a specific queue (TEST.QUEUE in this example).  The output will include both the `DEFINE Q` command along with `SET AUTHREC` commands to restore any OAM permissions granted to that specific queue.  Note that this command will not backup OAM for any other queue or wild carded permissions.

```
dmpmqcfg -m qm.apple -n TEST.QUEUE -t queue -a -x all -o 1line
```

To backup the data in the queue you can use the [MO03 SupportPac (aka QLOAD)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009368) from IBM.  This SupportPac from IBM has been withdrawn because at v8 of the product it was integrated and renamed to dmpmqmsg.  For versions of MQ prior to v8 you can still download the MQ03 SupportPac at the above link.  The original author of the SupportPac also now maintains a version of the program called [QLOAD](http://www.mqgem.com/qload.html).

Example command below will backup a queue called TEST.QUEUE with out removing the messages from the queue (change the -i to capital -I to also remove them from the queue).

```
qload -m qm.apple -i TEST.QUEUE -f TEST.QUEUE.qload
```

Output will show how many messages were read and written, example output is below:

```
Read    - Files:   0  Messages:     3  Bytes:         4
Written - Files:   1  Messages:     3  Bytes:         4
```

Example command below will put the messages from the file back onto the queue.

```
qload -m qm.apple -f TEST.QUEUE.qload -o TEST.QUEUE
```

Comment: How can I check it gets backup?

Comment: The output of the qload program will show how many messages were read from the queue and written to the file, I have updated the answer with an example output.