# Put messages to MQ queue from command-line

Tags: ibm-mq

As part of the installation of our application, I need to put a bunch of xml messages into an MQ queue. To make it more complicated, the messages need to have the usr-folder of the RFH2-header set.

I found that `mqput2.exe` from the IBM RFHUtil is an ideal tool for this task. Unfortunately, I have been unable to make setting of the usr-folder work, the documentation is too vague. What am I doing wrong? Or, is there another command-line tool available that works better?

My prop. file for `mqput2` looks like this:

```
[header]
.....
*
* message type
*
* Allowed values for message type
*  1 - request
*  2 - reply
*  4 - report
*  8 - datagram
*  112 - MQE fields from MQE
*  113 - MQE fields
*  65536 to 999,999,999 - user
msgtype=8
.....
*
* rfh usage
* rfh = N for No rfh
* rfh = A for Automatic (look for RFH at beginning of data file)
* rfh = 1 or V1 for Version 1 rfh from parameters in parm file
* rfh = 2 or V2 for Version 2 rfh from parameters in parm file
* rfh = X for special V2 rfh with fixed portion only and format=xml
*
* only first character checked, except for V when second character is also checked
*
rfh=X

<usr>
  <NotificationType>RDS.Codebook.Changes</NotificationType>
</usr>
.....
[filelist]
file1.xml
```

`mqput2` simply ignores the `<usr>` section and doesn't include it with the message. I've also tried `rfh=A` and put the `<usr>` section at the beginning of the `file1.xml` file, but then I get MQPUT error `reason=2142` (invalid MQ header structure).

Comment: rfh=2 should be the correct one

Comment: rfh=2 doesn't allow adding the usr params, at least according to the documentation: "If an individual field in a particular folder is specified...This technique cannot be used for the pscr or usr folders..." (ih03.doc from RFHUtil, p.88). Anyway, after changing to rfh=2, I get reason code 2142.

Comment: Look at page 82 and 83: "If the RFH parameter is set to a value of 2, then the utility will build an RFH header and insert it before the data when writing a message.  The contents of the folders in the RFH header can be specified either as individual fields or as a block of text in an XML format."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it set up this way, and it works fine:

```
[header]
qname=QName
qmgr=QMName
msgcount=1
format= "MQSTR   "
codepage=1208
rfh=2
<usr>
<test>test</test>
</usr>
[filelist]
test.xml
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Not only that rfh must be 2, but also format must be MQSTR. Which is strange, because from RFHUtil itself, format MQHRF2  must be used, while format MQSTR does not include the RFH header !?!

Answer (score 3):

Also dmpmqmsg utility, which is part of the WMQ8 installation, can be used for sending the messages from command-line. A message can be exported from a queue including the headers via

```
dmpmqmsg -m queue_manager> -I <queue> -f <msg_file> -a
```

and then submitted again via (I think, consult the docs)

```
dmpmqmsg -m queue_manager> -o <queue> -f <msg_file>
```

This utility is however not part of WMQ 7.5.

Comment: To backup the data in the queue you can use the [MO03 SupportPac (aka QLOAD)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24009368) from IBM.  This SupportPac from IBM has been withdrawn because at v8 of the product it was integrated and renamed to dmpmqmsg.  For versions of MQ prior to v8 you can still download the MQ03 SupportPac at the above link.  The original author of the SupportPac also now maintains a version of the program called [QLOAD](http://www.mqgem.com/qload.html).

Comment: See my answer to post "[How to IBM MQ - Backup and Clearing Messages on queues in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517793/how-to-ibm-mq-backup-and-clearing-messages-on-queues-in-linux/41518179#41518179)" for more information.

Comment: Yes, in your link they write explicitly that "MO03 qload is now (from MQ v8) part of the product - renamed to dmpmqmsg". So `qload` is the predecessor of `dmpmqmsg` for WMQ 7.5.

Comment: was just providing two alternatives for MQ prior to v8.