# Route messages to different message queues in IBM MQ based on MQRFH2 and USR properties

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

Would appreciate if anyone is able to assist/provide some sort of a guide/tutorial for using IBM IIB (Integrated Toolkit) and IBM MQ, making use of MQ Input Node, Compute Node and MQ Output Node, such that when a message is put on the input queue, it will be routed to an output queue based on the MQRFH2 headers and USR properties set/defined in the compute node (ESQL file)

E.g. If MQRFH2/USR = 1, route message to Queue 1, IF MQRFH2/USR = 2, route message to Queue 2, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for, sample code? Your question is too general. But in general, you can set the destination queue via the OutputLocalEnvironment in your Compute node, and you can have a simple IF statement to set the target queue depending on the incoming usr header.

Comment: You can also use Route node OR RouteToLabel node in IIB to have a visual representation of the routing in the message flow. But if you have lot more number of queues and you plan to keep dynamically adding queues and do not want to touch IIB code in the future, your best option is to set the destination queue via the OutputLocalEnvironment in your Compute node as explained by other commenters in this post.

Comment: Hi Attila, thanks for your input. Any ideas on how to put a message from IBM MQ Explorer with usr header in the message? Am i able to do that?

Comment: @ker shen - you can use RHutil tool to set the headers.  https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil

Comment: @ker shen - if my input helped you can mark it as useful so that it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read [Accessing the MQRFH2 header](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac16910_.html) and [Populating Destination in the local environment tree](http://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac16862_.html).

Then you could write your ESQL like this: (assuming the RFH2 routing variable is named `Ker`)

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE Routing_Compute
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.MQ.DestinationData[1].queueName =
            CASE InputRoot.MQRFH2.usr.Ker
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Q1'
                WHEN '2' THEN 'Q2'
                ELSE 'Q3'
            END;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

Remember to change the default node configuration like this:

- Compute: Set `Compute mode` to `LocalEnvironment`
- MQ Ouput: Set `Destination mode` to `Destination List`

Example: If input message header `Ker` has value `2`, then it will be routed to queue `Q2`.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for the code and pointers. I have tried to implement the above but when I put a message on the queue (as specified in the MQ Input Node) with input message header Ker value of either '1' or '2', the message gets routed to the queue in the ELSE statement.

May I check what should be the correct syntax to put the test message on my input queue (from IBM MQ)?
I have tried <Ker=1>myMessage, <Ker='1'>myMessage , <Ker="1">myMessage, etc. but cannot seem to get the desired result. Would greatly appreciate any inputs from your end, TIA.

Comment: With what kind of tool are you send the MQ message to the input node? I just tried with IIB Toolkit Flow Exerciser, but I could not set the RFH2 header; seems not to work.

Comment: I am using both the flow exerciser on IBM Toolkit and on MQ Explorer. Both route my messages to the queue in ELSE.

Comment: With MQ Explorer you can not set RFH2 headers. I will try something else and will let you know.

Comment: Alright, Thank you !
I am only able to work with IBM MQ and IIB Toolkit so it will really be helpful if I can create this scenario just by using IBM MQ/IIB Toolkit.

Comment: I can not convince the Flow Exerciser to include RFH2 header. You have to open a PMR with IBM to get this fixed. If you can use the command line, use the [mqput2.exe](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil/raw/master/bin/Release/mqput2.exe) utility from the [mq-rfhutil](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-rfhutil) package. This works for sure, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44645186/638413) answer.

Comment: @kershen I opened an IBM case for the Flow Exerciser issue. Should you have troubles using mqput2 to put an MQ message with RFH2 headers, and my linked answer does not help you, then ask another question on Stack Overflow with your specific problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have managed to get it to work using rfhutil, thanks!